# Disable Scrolling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

In code, RecyclerView is in ViewPager. 
I wanted enable scrolling in ViewPager when RecyclerView larger than ViewPager.
Unfold All list in recyclerView, How can scroll only viewPager? 
I did `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` but not working and not good way.

Here is my code

**fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="StoreFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
    //...
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorGray">
    //...
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
    //...
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textMenuMain"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Activity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Toolbar...>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                app:tabTextColor="#000" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment.java**

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    List<String> list;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        recyclerView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMenu);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
            list.add(i+1 + "List");
        }

        adapter = new MenuListAdapter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return viewGroup;
    }
}

class MenuListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<String> list ;

    public MenuListAdapter(List<String> lists){
        this.list = lists;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.store_menu_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String text = list.get(position);
        holder.textMenuName.setText(text);
        holder.textMenuPrice.setText("Price:00");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textMenuName;
        TextView textMenuPrice;
        Button buttonCartAdd;

        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            textMenuName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMenuName);
            textMenuPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMenuPrice);
            buttonCartAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCartAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
    public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TextView textViewNotice;
    TextView textViewTitle;
    String title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_detail);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        textViewNotice = findViewById(R.id.textNotice);
        textViewTitle = findViewById(R.id.textTitle);

        textViewNotice.setSelected(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        title = intent.getExtras().getString("Title");
        textViewTitle.setText(title);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("정보"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("리뷰"));

        Activity.MyPagerAdapter adapter = new Activity.MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        Fragment Fragment = new Fragment();
        adapter.addItem(Fragment);
        //...


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }


    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        ArrayList<Fragment> items = new ArrayList<>();

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addItem(Fragment item) {
            items.add(item);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
 @Override
 public boolean canScrollVertically() {
  return false;
 }
};

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```